# Not logging in with correct password and username

Tags: 18.04

My ubuntu 18.4.1 is not logging in. I tried to change it from root user from grub menu but after doing this successfully the result is same .When i login with tty3 with same password it is login in but not login in GUI screen

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  If your $HOME (/home/user/) directory is full, or near-full and has insufficient space for the temporary work files that are needed for gui, the login fails and you return to the greeter (or login) screen.  This is one cause, and what I check first (*assuming it's not a new machine, or I've just changed graphics drivers etc*).  Given you've not mentioned doing anything, I'd check you have some free space in your $HOME

Answer (score 0):

There is a dropdown menu where you can tick your desired [distrubution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions#Ubuntu-based) when loging in. It is where the gear icon is located [here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ubuntu-17.10-login-screen-750x421.jpg).

Comment: Please extend your answer. What do you mean with _distribution_? Where is the dropdown? Could you provide a screenshot, maybe like [this one](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ubuntu-17.10-login-screen-750x421.jpg)?

Comment: I reinstalled windows didnt find any solution . Thanks for your help :)